# Datalog program containment

Tags: database, logic-programming, datalog

given two Datalog programs `P1, P2` I would like to check if `P1` is contained in `P2`, i.e. on every Database `D`, the ouput of `P1` is contained in `P2`.

For example, `P1`:

```
A(X,Y) :- a(X,Y)
```

and program `P2`:

```
A'(X,Y) :- a(X,Y), b(X,Y)
```

it is clear that for every possible Database `A' contained in A`, because `b(X,Y)` only filters results from `a(X,Y)` thus the containment.

Is there a standard Datalog implementation that returns true/false on this kind of query?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot express directly the containment, but you can create a predicate that verifies if it exists any element in P1 that not exists in P2, and through negation, you can infer if the set is contained or not in the other set.

```
not_contain(X,Y) :- A(X,Y), not A'(X,Y) .
check_containment(C) :- count(not_containt(_,_), C) .
```

I'm assuming that you use datalog with negation. If check_containment is equal to 0, it means that `P1` is contained in `P2`.

Comment: This can be a solution for a particular knowledge base  containing specific facts. I would like to check if it is contained for every possible knowledgeable

Answer (score 0):

In 1993 paper [Equivalence of datalog queries is undecidable](https://doi.org/10.1016/0743-1066(93)90040-N) Oded Shmueli showed it is in general impossible:

```
It is shown that determining containment or equivalence of Datalog queries is
recursively unsolvable.
```

The reason for this result is that rules may be 'recursive' (aka 'non-tight'):

```
ancestor(X, Z) :- ancestor(X, Y), parent(Y, Z)
```

and recursion makes the problem undecidable.

It may, however, be possible for fragments of datalog, see [Query Containment for Highly Expressive Datalog Fragments](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7801.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I have read both papers. The general problem is undecidable, but I was searching for a program that works on small instances with some timeout option. Moreover, not all programs are recursive, but I have not found a normal containment checking program

Comment: if heads in the rules are unique in each program and there's no negation or recursion used, then both programs are in fact Conjuctive Queries. containment for CQ is decidable, see: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/1030/qw.pdf